# Custom XML feed based on .Net MVC model

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-5, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api2

We're redoing a legacy application using .Net MVC 5. Part of the application generates an XML feed which other applications use.

We've built a model called Call

```cs
[XmlRoot("record")]
public class Call
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string CustomerInitials { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("starttime")]
    public DateTime Entry { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("endtime")]
    public DateTime Exit { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("cnumber")][NotMapped]
    public string Number
    {
        get { return Prefix + Code + CustomerNumber; } 
    }
}
```

With a controller:

```cs
public class CallsController : ApiController
{
    private DbContext db = new DbContext();

    // GET: api/Calls
    public IQueryable<Call> GetCalls()
    {
        return db.Calls;
    }
}
```

Which produces an XML feed of:

```
  <ArrayOfCall xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Call>
      <starttime>2016-01-15T14:45:24.447</starttime>
      <endtime>2016-01-15T15:45:24.447</endtime>
    </Call>
    <Call>
      <starttime>2016-01-15T15:46:35.637</starttime>
      <endtime>2016-01-15T16:46:35.637</endtime>
    </Call>
  </ArrayOfCall>
```

However, I need to customize the XML feed to provide the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
    <RECORD>
        <CNUMBER>593042401</CNUMBER>
        <STARTTIME>2016-01-15T14:45:24.447</STARTTIME>
        <ENDTIME>2016-01-15T15:45:24.447</ENDTIME>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <CNUMBER>593042401</CNUMBER>
        <STARTTIME>2016-01-15T15:46:35.637</STARTTIME>
        <ENDTIME>2016-01-15T16:46:35.637</ENDTIME>
    </RECORD>
</DATA>
```

The XmlRoot data annotation is not followed and the CNumber is not included in my XML feed. The calls should display as `<record>` in the XML feed with the root being `<data>`. How do I resolve these issues? Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I be using a View Model instead?

Comment: Could Number be null on call completion? This could explain why it doesnt show in the original XML.

Comment: I've checked my local database and there are values for each one of the fields that the Number field uses. Maybe it's because it's a composite field (might not be the right term for it)?

Answer (score 2):

1.- The Data class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Call
    {
        [XmlIgnore]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string CustomerInitials { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("CNUMBER")]
        public string Number
        {
            get { return Prefix + Code + CustomerNumber; }
        }
        [XmlElement("STARTTIME")]
        public DateTime Entry { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ENDTIME")]
        public DateTime Exit { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DATA")]
    public class Data
    {
        [XmlElement("RECORD")]
        public List<Call> Calls;
    }
}
```

2.- Using your example data:

```
    //  1.- Data
    var data = new Data();
    var calls = new List<Call>
    {
        new Call
        {
            Entry = new DateTime(2016, 1, 15, 14, 45, 24, 447),
            Exit = new DateTime(2016, 1, 15, 15, 45, 24, 447)
        },
        new Call
        {
            Entry = new DateTime(2016, 1, 15, 15, 46, 35, 637),
            Exit = new DateTime(2016, 1, 15, 16, 46, 35, 637)
        }
    };
    data.Calls = new List<Call>(calls);

    //  2.- Serialize the objet to byte[]
    var dataByteArray = new XmlSerializerHelper<Data>().ObjectToByteArray(data, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"), true);

    //  3.- Save the byte[] to disk
    File.WriteAllBytes("D:/xml.xml", dataByteArray);
```

3.- The serializer helper:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class XmlSerializerHelper<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly XmlSerializer _serializer;

        public XmlSerializerHelper()
        {
            _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        }

        public byte[] ObjectToByteArray(T obj, Encoding encoding = null, bool ignoreNAmespaces = false)
        {
            var settings = GetSettings(encoding);
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, settings))
                {
                    if (ignoreNAmespaces)
                    {
                        var serializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                        serializerNamespaces.Add("", "");
                        _serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, serializerNamespaces);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
                    }
                }
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        private XmlWriterSettings GetSettings(Encoding encoding)
        {
            return new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"),
                Indent = true,
                IndentChars = "\t",
                NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document
            };
        }
    }
}
```

4.- Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DATA>
    <RECORD>
        <STARTTIME>2016-01-15T14:45:24.447</STARTTIME>
        <ENDTIME>2016-01-15T15:45:24.447</ENDTIME>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <STARTTIME>2016-01-15T15:46:35.637</STARTTIME>
        <ENDTIME>2016-01-15T16:46:35.637</ENDTIME>
    </RECORD>
</DATA>
```

Cheers

Comment: I don't want to create a static XML file. The Xml file is currently located at /api/{controller}.

Comment: It just an example, you do not specify the type of output. Your problem was the serialization and the above code solves the problem. Let me know if you have any questions.

Cheers

Comment: @dspencer, 

Then, you have any questions related to your main question?

Answer (score 0):

To create XML that would match the what you are wanting you could create an Object named Data which could provide a list that would hold Records.

```
public class Data{
   public List<Record> Records{get;set;}
}
```

Currently you are returning an array of Calls.

Comment: I'm returning Calls because we're redoing the application and the actual model is a call. Would adding a data annotation to the Class model allow for adding the calls as a record tag?